# Pushing all local branches to other remotes in Git

Tags: git

I am fetching `origin` like this:

```
git fetch origin
```

This will get all branches as `master` and `dev`.

Then I push it to another remote `mirror-server`:

```
git push mirror-server master
```

Or, basically `git push --all mirror-server`.

But this does not push my `dev` branch to `mirror-server`, only `master` branch is pushed.

Error I get:

```
error: src refspec dev does not match any.
```

As shown I tried:

```
git push -u mirror-server dev
git push --all
```

I also tried switching curent branch and then push. No luck! Only one time I got something and it was this: Git basically put all files on `dev` to `master` and merge files…

Basically I need to pull changes from `origin` and then push ALL branches to ALL other remotes.

Comment: `! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)`

Comment: To be more clear, When i pull origin there was no datas on the local folder and also there is no master and dev branch on mirror server. Mirror server only create master branch but when i want to push dev branch it throws an error. I cannot automatically create dev branch on mirror server. Only origin has dev branch currently. I want to be synced. If origin has a new branch then mirror server must have it

Comment: @Palec, i will follow it but can you just see this page: `https://github.com/nhnc-nginx/apache2nginx`. As you see, this has two branch. `master` and `gh-pages`. I can do `git fetch` and then push master but not `gh-pages` to my other server. I will try  new test now.

Comment: Appearently, i have to checkout each branch before push.. Interesting. After checking out dev and master manually i can push with --all and done.

Comment: That’s what I said. You tried pushing a non-existent local branch `dev`. You had just the `origin/dev` tracking branch.

Comment: BTW by `git push --all` you meant `git push --all mirror-server`, didn’t you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sequence of commands clones your GitHub repository (or any other repository if you change the URL) to `~/local-repos`, initializes an empty repository in `~/remote-repos.git` and pushes from `~/local-repos` to `~/remote-repos.git` all branches.

```
git clone 'https://github.com/nhnc-nginx/apache2nginx' ~/local-repos
git init --bare ~/remote-repos.git
cd ~/local-repos
git remote add mirror-server ~/remote-repos.git
git push --mirror mirror-server
```

Later you update tracking branches (and get new ones) in your `~/local-repos` with `git fetch origin` executed inside `~/local-repos`. You can mirror everything to `~/remote-repos.git` again with [`git push --mirror mirror-server`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html). If you want to push a single branch (e.g. `origin/gh-pages`), use `git push mirror-server origin/gh-pages`.

Notice that `https://github.com/nhnc-nginx/apache2nginx` remote is named `origin` automatically. `git fetch origin` fetches accessible objects from `origin` repository and stores branches as tracking branches. Tracking branches are prefixed with the remote name (`origin` in this case). If you perform `git checkout gh-pages` and no `gh-pages` branch exists, Git performs `git branch --track gh-pages origin/gh-pages` before performing the checkout, which creates the `gh-pages` branch with upstream set to `origin/gh-pages`.

This was probably the source of the errors your Git reported. You fetched just `origin/gh-pages` and tried to push non-existent `gh-pages` branch. As part of checkout, `gh-pages` was created, so push work then.

Also notice that you are creating a mirror of your local repository, not `origin`. If you want to mirror your GitHub repository, you should execute `git fetch origin` inside the just created empty mirror with `git remote add origin 'https://github.com/nhnc-nginx/apache2nginx'`.